# How can I turn this text structure by using Regular Expression into a different structure?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have a file of cities and provinces in a json format. I want to insert it to my database table but the structure is in json format. I need to remove some numbers and add the structure to properly insert it to my table.

Here's the sample of the text of my file.

`"246":"Bangued","278":"Boliney","287":"Bucay","309":"Bucloc","314":"Daguioman","319":"Danglas","327":"Dolores","343":"LaPaz","356":"Lacub","363":"Lagangilang","381":"Lagayan","387":"Langiden","394":"Licuan~Baay","406":"Luba","415":"Malibcong","428":"Manabo","440":"Penarrubia","450":"Pidigan","466":"Pilar","486":"Sallapadan","496":"San Isidro","506":"San Juan","526":"San Quintin","533":"Tayum","545":"Tineg","556":"Tubo","567":"Villaviciosa"`

I want to turn it into:

```
(NULL, "1", "Bangued"),
(NULL, "1", "Boliney"),
(NULL, "1", "Bucay"),
(NULL, "1", "Bucloc"),
(NULL, "1", "Daguioman"),
(NULL, "1", "Danglas"),
(NULL, "1", "Dolores"),
(NULL, "1", "La Paz"),
(NULL, "1", "Lacub"),
(NULL, "1", "Lagangilang"),
(NULL, "1", "Lagayan"),
(NULL, "1", "Langiden"),
(NULL, "1", "Licuan~Baay"),
(NULL, "1", "Luba"),
(NULL, "1", "Malibcong"),
(NULL, "1", "Manabo"),
(NULL, "1", "Penarrubia"),
(NULL, "1", "Pidigan"),
(NULL, "1", "Pilar"),
(NULL, "1", "Sallapadan"),
(NULL, "1", "San Isidro"),
(NULL, "1", "San Juan"),
(NULL, "1", "San Quintin"),
(NULL, "1", "Tayum"),
(NULL, "1", "Tineg"),
(NULL, "1", "Tubo"),
(NULL, "1", "Villaviciosa"),
```

Can you tell me how to do this in regular expression?

Comment: Are the `1`'s in the desired output correct or should it actually be `246`, `278`, `287`, etc. (values from input).

Comment: Which language / tool you are trying to do this in / with? Also, have you tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: yes i tried it solving myself. It works but i need to do it one by one like remove the numbers first then remove the quotes. then i replace the province into the statement that i want. i don't have a one line code to do it. the 1 is the desired output. im using sublime text 2 to do the regular expression search and replace.

Comment: you see it was cumbersome to do that. i have like 92 cities to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/"[0-9]*":\("[a-zA-Z ~]*"\),/(NULL, "1", \1),\
/g'
```

The backslash is followed by a newline character.

Comment: i have never used sed before. so this will be my first try. thanks for offering me better alternatives.

Comment: The `[a-zA-Z]` doesn't cover everything - e.g `Licuan~Baay` and `San Isidro`. `[^"]` would probably be a better option.

Comment: @Dukeling: Thanks for pointing that out.  I added space and ~ in the set to fix it.  Raymond can add other characters as needed.

Comment: its working. thank you so much for this. i have never used sed and now i found it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This combination of `tr` and `sed` works for your sample data:

```
tr ',' '\n' < yourfile.txt | tr ':' ',' | sed 's/^/\(NULL, /g;s/$/\),/g;s/"[0-9]*"/"1" /g'
```

But there is one issue, mainly if any of the strings contain `:` or `,` then it will be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with `sublimetext2` and you mentioned that you're using that editor to do this, here's a sublime answer.

You can do this in less than a minute without using regex.  Just use the built-in functions of the editor.

### Initial selection

So you start with your long list of stuff on a single line it seems:

"246":"Bangued","278":"Boliney","287":"Bucay","309":"Bucloc","314":"Daguioman","319":"Danglas","327":"Dolores","343":"LaPaz","356":"Lacub","363":"Lagangilang","381":"Lagayan","387":"Langiden","394":"Licuan~Baay","406":"Luba","415":"Malibcong","428":"Manabo","440":"Penarrubia","450":"Pidigan","466":"Pilar","486":"Sallapadan","496":"San Isidro","506":"San Juan","526":"San Quintin","533":"Tayum","545":"Tineg","556":"Tubo","567":"Villaviciosa"

[image]

Since the format is the same for everything here, you can use that to your advantage.  Highlight a colon.  You should end up with something like this (I chose the first colon, but it doesn't really matter which you start with, in this case):

"246"`:`"Bangued","278":"Boliney","287":"Bucay","309":"Bucloc","314":"Daguioman","319":"Danglas","327":"Dolores","343":"LaPaz","356":"Lacub","363":"Lagangilang","381":"Lagayan","387":"Langiden","394":"Licuan~Baay","406":"Luba","415":"Malibcong","428":"Manabo","440":"Penarrubia","450":"Pidigan","466":"Pilar","486":"Sallapadan","496":"San Isidro","506":"San Juan","526":"San Quintin","533":"Tayum","545":"Tineg","556":"Tubo","567":"Villaviciosa"

[image]

Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.  This will select every colon there.  So you'll end up like this:

"246"`:`"Bangued","278"`:`"Boliney","287"`:`"Bucay","309"`:`"Bucloc","314"`:`"Daguioman","319"`:`"Danglas","327"`:`"Dolores","343"`:`"LaPaz","356"`:`"Lacub","363"`:`"Lagangilang","381"`:`"Lagayan","387"`:`"Langiden","394"`:`"Licuan~Baay","406"`:`"Luba","415"`:`"Malibcong","428"`:`"Manabo","440"`:`"Penarrubia","450"`:`"Pidigan","466"`:`"Pilar","486"`:`"Sallapadan","496"`:`"San Isidro","506"`:`"San Juan","526"`:`"San Quintin","533"`:`"Tayum","545"`:`"Tineg","556"`:`"Tubo","567"`:`"Villaviciosa"

[image]

### Out with the old

Now, you want to grab all of those numbers and convert them to `(NULL, "1",`  So press the right arrow <kbd>→</kbd>in order to get to the end of each selection:

[image]

Then shift-select each number.  You can do this a couple of ways.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> will go by word boundaries
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> will go by character boundaries

You might have to play with it in order to find what works best for you.  In any case, you want to end up with this selection:

`"246":`"Bangued",`"278":`"Boliney",`"287":`"Bucay",`"309":`"Bucloc",`"314":`"Daguioman",`"319":`"Danglas",`"327":`"Dolores",`"343":`"LaPaz",`"356":`"Lacub",`"363":`"Lagangilang",`"381":`"Lagayan",`"387":`"Langiden",`"394":`"Licuan~Baay",`"406":`"Luba",`"415":`"Malibcong",`"428":`"Manabo",`"440":`"Penarrubia",`"450":`"Pidigan",`"466":`"Pilar",`"486":`"Sallapadan",`"496":`"San Isidro",`"506":`"San Juan",`"526":`"San Quintin",`"533":`"Tayum",`"545":`"Tineg",`"556":`"Tubo",`"567":`"Villaviciosa"

[image]

### In with the new

Now, just start typing the `(NULL, "1",`.  It will replace each selected instance with that.

*Note*: You may have it set up to auto-insert a closing paren, just delete that for now

So you end up with:

(NULL, "1", "Bangued",(NULL, "1", "Boliney",(NULL, "1", "Bucay",(NULL, "1", "Bucloc",(NULL, "1", "Daguioman",(NULL, "1", "Danglas",(NULL, "1", "Dolores",(NULL, "1", "LaPaz",(NULL, "1", "Lacub",(NULL, "1", "Lagangilang",(NULL, "1", "Lagayan",(NULL, "1", "Langiden",(NULL, "1", "Licuan~Baay",(NULL, "1", "Luba",(NULL, "1", "Malibcong",(NULL, "1", "Manabo",(NULL, "1", "Penarrubia",(NULL, "1", "Pidigan",(NULL, "1", "Pilar",(NULL, "1", "Sallapadan",(NULL, "1", "San Isidro",(NULL, "1", "San Juan",(NULL, "1", "San Quintin",(NULL, "1", "Tayum",(NULL, "1", "Tineg",(NULL, "1", "Tubo",(NULL, "1", "Villaviciosa"

[image]

### Closing the paren

Now, since you have some provinces with word separators, tilde and space, you have to approach the  rest of this from the other side.  Highlight a `,(` and again press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> in order to select all of them (I chose `,(` instead of just `(` in order to exclude the very first `(`:

(NULL, "1", "Bangued"`,(`NULL, "1", "Boliney"`,(`NULL, "1", "Bucay"`,(`NULL, "1", "Bucloc"`,(`NULL, "1", "Daguioman"`,(`NULL, "1", "Danglas"`,(`NULL, "1", "Dolores"`,(`NULL, "1", "LaPaz"`,(`NULL, "1", "Lacub"`,(`NULL, "1", "Lagangilang"`,(`NULL, "1", "Lagayan"`,(`NULL, "1", "Langiden"`,(`NULL, "1", "Licuan~Baay"`,(`NULL, "1", "Luba"`,(`NULL, "1", "Malibcong"`,(`NULL, "1", "Manabo"`,(`NULL, "1", "Penarrubia"`,(`NULL, "1", "Pidigan"`,(`NULL, "1", "Pilar"`,(`NULL, "1", "Sallapadan"`,(`NULL, "1", "San Isidro"`,(`NULL, "1", "San Juan"`,(`NULL, "1", "San Quintin"`,(`NULL, "1", "Tayum"`,(`NULL, "1", "Tineg"`,(`NULL, "1", "Tubo"`,(`NULL, "1", "Villaviciosa"

[image]

Press <kbd>←</kbd> in order to go to the beginning of your selection.  Now close down your parens with `)`.  So you end up like this:

(NULL, "1", "Bangued"),(NULL, "1", "Boliney"),(NULL, "1", "Bucay"),(NULL, "1", "Bucloc"),(NULL, "1", "Daguioman"),(NULL, "1", "Danglas"),(NULL, "1", "Dolores"),(NULL, "1", "LaPaz"),(NULL, "1", "Lacub"),(NULL, "1", "Lagangilang"),(NULL, "1", "Lagayan"),(NULL, "1", "Langiden"),(NULL, "1", "Licuan~Baay"),(NULL, "1", "Luba"),(NULL, "1", "Malibcong"),(NULL, "1", "Manabo"),(NULL, "1", "Penarrubia"),(NULL, "1", "Pidigan"),(NULL, "1", "Pilar"),(NULL, "1", "Sallapadan"),(NULL, "1", "San Isidro"),(NULL, "1", "San Juan"),(NULL, "1", "San Quintin"),(NULL, "1", "Tayum"),(NULL, "1", "Tineg"),(NULL, "1", "Tubo"),(NULL, "1", "Villaviciosa"

[image]

### Inserting the newline

The cursor is still at each closing paren, but you need a newline after the comma.  Move one character to the right <kbd>→</kbd>(you want to get beyond your comma there) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> to enter a newline.  Your lines now look like this:

```
(NULL, "1", "Bangued"),
(NULL, "1", "Boliney"),
(NULL, "1", "Bucay"),
(NULL, "1", "Bucloc"),
(NULL, "1", "Daguioman"),
(NULL, "1", "Danglas"),
(NULL, "1", "Dolores"),
(NULL, "1", "LaPaz"),
(NULL, "1", "Lacub"),
(NULL, "1", "Lagangilang"),
(NULL, "1", "Lagayan"),
(NULL, "1", "Langiden"),
(NULL, "1", "Licuan~Baay"),
(NULL, "1", "Luba"),
(NULL, "1", "Malibcong"),
(NULL, "1", "Manabo"),
(NULL, "1", "Penarrubia"),
(NULL, "1", "Pidigan"),
(NULL, "1", "Pilar"),
(NULL, "1", "Sallapadan"),
(NULL, "1", "San Isidro"),
(NULL, "1", "San Juan"),
(NULL, "1", "San Quintin"),
(NULL, "1", "Tayum"),
(NULL, "1", "Tineg"),
(NULL, "1", "Tubo"),
(NULL, "1", "Villaviciosa"
```

The last step is to finish the last line.  It never got the closing paren and comma.  So go to the last line and do that.

[image]

This took about half an hour to write up, but less than a minute to actually do.  It's kind of hard to explain with just text, but the key here is that you can solve this issue without asking others how to use a regex.  And it can be done much quicker.  Using multi-select takes a bit of getting used to, but it is worth it in the end for the amount of time you save.